# For the end of Season 2, what are the new Elo bracket percentiles?

Tags: league-of-legends

For example, before the new brackets were introduced:

Bronze: Between 1250 and 1399 (3v3: 1249-1409, pre-made 5v5: 1249-1409) (Top 25%)

---

<sup>Question from the [League of Legends forums](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=29199700).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We didn't use exact percentiles because we feel that it's more
>   important that the requirements are consistent and easy to remember.
>   But it's roughly:
>
> - Diamond - Top 0.05% to 0.1%
> - Platinum - Top 0.5% to 1%
> - Gold - Top 5% to 10%
> - Silver - Top 40% to 50%

--[Yegg, Senior Game Designer](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=29199700)

And as the new season progresses, you can find updated percentiles on [LoL Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elo_rating_system).